# Carrierwave or Paperclip as uploader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip, carrierwave, image-uploading

Can someone tell me what the advantages of both?
I've been reading about them, but I'm still in doubt, maybe someone could help me choose.

I want to use for many types of files, including image manipulation.

My project is Rails 3.1 with Ruby 1.9.2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look also at [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) it has a lot of features and it is very simple to use.

Comment: Thanks @Fabio, Im testing this now :)